# Generating an XML file with large amounts of data and avoid memory cap

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with about 300k pages in it now, and a server with 1GB of memory. Unfortunately, all of the sitemap generating plugins can no longer handle it. I've tried 3 different methods of writing to XML with PHP (XMLWriter, SimpleXMLElement, and DOMDocument) and they all end up capping out at around 30k pages (xml nodes).

What do you think I could do to make this work? Worst case scenario, I thought about setting up multiple cron jobs that would run every ten minutes once a day and keep opening/appending to the file and just add to it in chunks, but that's obviously not an optimal solution. I found some snippet that claimed to be able to flush out the memory during my loop, but it didn't do the trick either. Here's an example of that snippet:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';
for ($i = 0 ; $i< 20; $i++) {
  $query = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT ID, post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' LIMIT %s,%s", $i*10000, 10000));
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $xml .= '<url>';
    $xml .= '<loc>'.get_permalink($row['ID']).'</loc>';
    $xml .= '<lastmod>'.$row['post_date'].'</lastmod>';
    $xml .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
    $xml .= '<priority>0.6</priority>';
    $xml .= '</url>';
  }
}
$xml .= '</urlset>';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->asXML("sitemap.xml");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you grabbing all the records at once?

Try get 10000 rows per request. And clean up memory after every iteration.

If you run in cli mode older versions of php do not release memory so you can try to fork  http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

How to do it:

1. No need to use any xml library, `sprintf` would do the trick.
2. Wrap it in to for ($i = 0, $i < 5, $i++) {}
3. Query would look like `LIMIT ($i*10000) 10000`

Code Example:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i< 5 $i++) {
    ...
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT ? ?');
    $sth->execute(array($i*10000, 10000));
    ...
}
```

Another code example:

```
    <?php
    $fileHandle = fopen("sitemap.xml", "w");

    fwrite($fileHandle,
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . 
        '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"' .
        ' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' .
        ' xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9' .
        ' http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">'
    );

    for ($i = 0 ; $i< 20; $i++) {
        $query = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT ID, post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' LIMIT %s,%s", $i*10000, 10000));
        $xml = '';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $xml .= '<url>'.
                '<loc>'.get_permalink($row['ID']).'</loc>' .
                '<lastmod>'.$row['post_date'].'</lastmod>' .
                '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>' .
                '<priority>0.6</priority>' .
                '</url>';
        }

        fwrite($fileHandle, $xml);
    }
    fwrite($fileHandle, '</urlset>');

    fclose($fileHandle);

    echo PHP_EOL . 'memory used: '. memory_get_peak_usage() . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I'm a little new to dealing with data on this kind of scale. I know I can limit the amount of records I pull in, but how do I tell it to do what you're recommending? (as in pull in 10,000, clear memory, pull in the next 10,000, etc., all in the same script). Thanks!  :)

Comment: Ok, trying to get the syntax on the mysql query correct. It's not liking what I'm putting in there with `for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT ID, post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' LIMIT ($i*10000) 10000")`

Comment: Sorry first thing to do would be replace mysql_* with http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php as mysql_* is depricated.

Comment: Updated post with example(PDO). If you do not want to change to pdo, use mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT %s %s', $i*10000, 10000))

Comment: AWESOME thank you, that worked beautifully (just needed a comma between the %s and %s). It sounds like I've got a lot to learn, I didn't even realize mysql_ was deprecated. I'm using it for now, but would like to change that. Any good resources you know of for making that switch?

Comment: Dang, actually, I still ended up running out of memory (but it made it to about 160k instead of just 30k). Do you think dropping mysql_ would help, or do I need to look at other alternatives?

Comment: Google accepts only 50000 as a sitemap you can do multy xml site map. Google it. If your articles do not change do not regenerate old ones, only add new. And as i've said if it you run it as cli(as cron job) you can try to add forking http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: Also you can post your new code I can take a pick in it, if something else can be optimized.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've updated the code. If google only likes 50k at a time however, then I'll have to do a sitemap index like you mentioned I guess, maybe using the fork to create multiple files?

Comment: No need to use forking for creating multiple files. Try new version it should use less memory. And it should be easy to change to create multiple files.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Unfortunately, that seems to work even worse than the simplexmlelement :( it hit the cap with 20, dropped it to 15 and the same thing. It's looking like I'll just have to set up several cron jobs, but at least the code you gave me with sprintf will allow me to generate much much more at a time.